# Removing precision on integer variable solutions in CPLEX

Tags: integer, precision, cplex

I have an MIP model and for integer bounded variables I get solutions such as

1.0000000000584843894 or 1.11181941e-08

First one is 1 and second is 0 but reported as above. I like CPLEX to report exactly 1 and 0. Looks like CPLEX is allowing a binary variable to be slightly non-zero.

How can I enforce this in CPLEX? Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: which API do you use ? (C++, OPL, java ... )

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at the integrality tolerance parameter

and read a famous cplex technote:

[Why does a binary or integer variable take on a noninteger value in the solution?](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/397051)

Answer (score 0):

This question (or minor variants) comes up regularly on here and elsewhere. This is standard behaviour with almost all mathematical programming solvers. Almost all the arithmetic in these solvers is done using double precision floating point numbers or better. If you want to see exact numbers like 0 and 1 in your output then you should round them appropriately. If you are concerned that these 'almost' 0 and 1 values might lead to incorrect solutions, then you could try fixing their values in your model and re-solving. This is unlikely to be an issue unless your model already has some numerical stability issues.